# Updating React application

Tags: reactjs, caching, browser, react-redux, web-deployment

I have developed a react application which is hoisted as [www.movielust.in](http://www.movielust.in) .As the react application  creates cache inside the browser I am unable to see changes  at the same moment.As it loads the content directly from cache is there any way that I could  deploy th app in such a way that everytime  i push a change  it updates cache  or fresh reload automatically as other users won't understand such things.

Just to explain in more details.. If I desployed a new crousal on homescreen so if I open the website in icognito mode it shows the latest updated website but on the other hand  if I open it normally it uses  browser cache and open the same old website without updating new changes.. So I was thinking about anyway to update the app whenever I push a new change

Answer (score 0):

When your upload before that change your package.json build version it's might help you

Comment: ummm if I implement even a small change still if I keep changing package.json will that be worth doing it.?